# UnityのApplication.persistentDataPathからアクセス出来るストレージの区別について

Tags: android, unity3d

`Application.persistentDataPath` から取得出来るパスは `/data/data/com.xxx.xxx/files` になると思いますが、`AndroidManifest.xml` には

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

と記述しているので、端末によってデータを本体に書き込んだり、SD CARDに書き込んだりしてます。

この時、Unity側で現在データの書き込みを本体にしているのか、SD CARDにしているのかわかる方法を知っている方いらっしゃいますか？（知りたい理由は、ファイルダウンロードする時に現在だとエラーを通して容量がないというのを確認しているが、ダウンロードする前に確認してユーザーに知らせたいため）

本体の空容量と、SD CARDがある場合の空容量の取得はできるのですがUnityがどこに書き込んでいるかがわからなくて、容量チェックする時にどこを見ればいいのかがわからないのです。

Answer (score 1):

試した訳ではないので違ったらすいません。

ぐぐると下記サイトがでてきました

http://hiiro-game.seesaa.net/article/272455420.html

Playerの設定で`internal only`にするか、`external`にするか選べたりしませんか？

Comment: 設定状況をもっと書いとけばよかってですね。
Playerの設定では、internal onlyと設定してます。
Installの先もForce Internalと、すべて本体に設定してます。